# Can't connect via SSH from host Mac OS to guest Ubuntu: Host is down

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, networking

I'm pretty new to working with networks and I've been having trouble using SSH on my Mac terminal to connect to my guest Ubuntu machine.

I'm using VirtualBox and I have set up port forwarding accordingly.

When I run the code below:

```
(base) MacBook-Pro:~ my_name$ ssh ubuntu@172.30.1.59 -p 222
```

I get this as a result:

```
ssh: connect to host 172.30.1.59 port 22: Operation timed out
```

So I tried pinging my ip and this is the result I get:

```
PING 172.30.1.59 (172.30.1.59): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 7
```

From some Googling I saw that I should check my netstat, but I wasn't sure how to make sense of it :( but here's what I get from netstat -r

```
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Netif Expire
default            172.30.1.254       UGSc           en0       
127                localhost          UCS            lo0       
localhost          localhost          UH             lo0       
169.254            link#6             UCS            en0      !
172.30.1/24        link#6             UCS            en0      !
172.30.1.5         48:8d:36:10:67:23  UHLWI          en0   1185
172.30.1.50        68:fe:f7:a6:65:1d  UHLWIi         en0   1021
172.30.1.58/32     link#6             UCS            en0      !
172.30.1.59        link#6             UHRLWI         en0      !
172.30.1.254/32    link#6             UCS            en0      !
172.30.1.254       0:7:89:6d:4d:ce    UHLWIir        en0   1168
224.0.0/4          link#6             UmCS           en0      !
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI         en0       
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI         en0       
255.255.255.255/32 link#6             UCS            en0      !
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If port forwarding is properly set in Virtualbox networking, you should connect using this command:
`ssh -p 222 ubuntu@localhost`

Port forwarding in VBox's case forwards VM's ports (for ssh TCP 22) to an arbitary port on host. So you connect to the host essentially, `localhost`, not to the VM. This connection is forwarded to the port on the VM.

I also changed the order of `-p` and destination, because on the result you posted the error mentions, `port 22: Operation timed out` (it should be 222). I don't know if this is a typo or the real output, just in case use `-p` in front of destination.

In case you've set everything correctly and still have problems, I'd suggest changing the port on host to a high port ( > 1023), 2222 for example. The lower ports need to be opened by privileged user (root, sudoer). Perhaps a VBox service on macOS can open 222, but I'm not certain.

Comment: This worked! For some reason, it still only works when I use my full ip address in the command instead of "localhost", but I think assigning a higher port number made it work. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Apparently you've forwarded to 172.30.1.59 instead of 127.0.0.1 (localhost). It's possbile of course. Is your IP static? If not you'd better forward to 127.0.0.1, so that even if the IP changes, you can always connect. Also have in mind that by using 172.30.1.59 other devices in the same subnet can ssh to the VM, if you don't block the traffic using a firewall. If you forward to 127.0.0.1 only the host can ssh to VM. Of course it might be desirable to connect from other devices, just pointing out.

Comment: This makes sense! -- Just changed the port forwarding to 127.0.0.1 and it works perfectly with the command you have above